# zsh parameter expansion replacement pattern parses string differently if input is a variable instead of inlined

Tags: zsh, command-substitution

A zsh parameter expansion replacement pattern parses string differently if input is a variable instead of inlined.

I assume that it has something to do with character escaping, but am not sure how to work around it.

In the code below, `>`, `*` & `2.5.8` should be filtered out of the printf output, which occurs in the first parameter expansion using the variable `versions`.

But when the `curl` call is inlined, then the above 3 values are not filtered out.

How can I inline the `curl` call yet still filter out the 3 values?

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

setopt EXTENDED_GLOB

# variable: 3 values are correctly filtered out
versions=$(curl '--silent' '--location' 'https://api.sdkman.io/2/candidates/groovy/darwin/versions/list?current=2.5.8&installed=2.5.8')
printf -- '%s\n' ${${(Z+n+)versions//[*+>][ *+>]# [[:graph:]]##}}

# inlined: 3 values are not filtered out
printf -- '%s\n' ${${(Z+n+)$(curl '--silent' '--location' 'https://api.sdkman.io/2/candidates/groovy/darwin/versions/list?current=2.5.8&installed=2.5.8')//[*+>][ *+>]# [[:graph:]]##}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the `$(command)` substitution:

```
printf -- '%s\n' ${(Z+n+)"$(curl '--silent' '--location' 'https://api.sdkman.io/2/candidates/groovy/darwin/versions/list?current=2.5.8&installed=2.5.8')"//[*+>][ *+>]# [[:graph:]]##}
```

(There was one extra unnecessary `${}` around the expn, which is removed above)

---

In a default `zsh` shell, *parameter expansion* doesn't need quoting to avoid splitting by `IFS` (but it won't hurt either). Unquoted *command substitution* is subject to splitting by `IFS`, so quoting must be done to avoid that.

The manual `zshexpn(1)`:

> `PARAMETER EXPANSION`
>
> > Note in particular the fact that words of unquoted parameters are not automatically split on whitespace unless the option `SH_WORD_SPLIT` is set; see references to this option below for more details.  This is an important difference from other shells.  However, as in other shells, null words are elided from unquoted parameters' expansions.
>
> `COMMAND SUBSTITUTION`
>
> > If the substitution is not enclosed in double quotes, the output is broken into words using the `IFS` parameter.

---

Also, there may be other ways to go about removing those strings, e.g.

```
printf -- '%s\n' ${${=versions}:#([*+>-]|2.5.8)}
```

which could be used with an unquoted command substitution:

```
printf -- '%s\n' ${$(curl '--silent' '--location' 'https://api.sdkman.io/2/candi'\
'dates/groovy/darwin/versions/list?current=2.5.8&installed=2.5.8'):#([*+>-]|2.5.8)}
```

The above uses a parameter expansion in the form `${name:#pattern}`. The manual says:

> `${name:#pattern}` If the pattern matches the value of name, then substitute the empty string; otherwise, just substitute the value of name.  If name is an array the matching array elements are removed (use the `(M)` flag to remove the non-matched elements).

Comment: Thanks. The goal wasn't just to remove 2.5.8, it was to replace the non-whitespace text directly following the sequence of `[*+>][ *+>]# `.  So, hardcoding 2.5.8 won't work for my purposes.  But the quoting works.